# How to keep lambda parameter on the same line in scalafmt

Tags: scala, scalafmt

By default scalafmt will reformat code like this

```scala
myList(elem => 
  elem
    .doThing
    .doOtherThing
)
```

to look like this

```scala
myList(
  elem => 
    elem
      .doThing
      .doOtherThing
)
```

How can it be configured to leave the anonymous function parameter on the same line? Note that it already does this if you use curly brackets instead of parens.

Comment: If a multi-line lambda expression is desired, use curly braces, not parens.

Comment: I understand that is a common style convention, but sometimes using parens over curly brackets can catch typos at compile time. For example https://pastebin.com/RaM7zeD5. If you're interested in a more practical case, consider akka http inner route concatenation where you might miss a `~`.

Comment: Your example produces a warning: `warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; multiline expressions might require enclosing parentheses`. It's a really good idea to make warnings fatal, and in fact turn on as many warnings as possible :-)

Comment: I would still like to know the answer to the original question. But it's good to know this case can produce a warning. I do have fatal warnings on pretty much all the time, but don't see an error, what's the flag to enable the warning you got?

Comment: See https://tpolecat.github.io/2017/04/25/scalac-flags.html , in my opinion almost all of these warnings should be turned on to keep a project under control. Specifically the one in question here is: `-Ywarn-value-discard`